# ob_start difference between https and http?

Tags: php, http, https, http-headers, ob-start

Is there a different behaviour for ob_start, ob_end_flush, ob_end and ob_flush in https compared to http?

I have read the posts about difference between http and https:

[Difference between http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375134/difference-between-http-and-https)

[Difference between HTTPS and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093430/difference-between-https-and-ssl)

as I have read this one about ob_start & headers:

[Showing error pages when sending header with header() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245706/showing-error-pages-when-sending-header-with-header-function)

but I do not find the answer I need.

**My Case:**

I am flushing a loading image with ob_start on two websites.
They are using the exact same code.
The only difference is the protocol - one is http and one is https.

**The http one acts fine**

The site using **http** outputs the image and will then continue with the script.

**The https one acts different**

The site using **https** outputs the image always after the script has been completely processed.

Thanks. I am glad for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

- HTTPS sends data in blocks (records), which may be [16KB large](https://istlsfastyet.com/#server-performance). If your image is smaller than that, the server may wait for more data before sending a complete block.
- Your HTTPS is implemented by a reverse proxy, and the proxy waits for the entire response to be sent before forwarding anything.

If you're using php-fpm, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

If you're using nginx, try http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering

Comment: Thanks Kornel, it is the reverse proxy, that waits. 
Is there a way to overcome this, if I am using apache without php-fpm?